# Interpreting limit notations

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, notation

My question is: Are the following notations equivalent or not:

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{When}\;||\textbf{x}||\rightarrow 0,\;\text{then}\;\;\;\frac{f(\textbf{x})}{||\textbf{x}||}\rightarrow0$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\lim_{||\textbf{x}||\rightarrow0} \frac{f(\textbf{x})}{||\textbf{x}||}=0\;\;?$$

The way I'm reading these are:

$(1)$ When $||\textbf{x}||$ is approaching zero the fraction $\frac{f(\textbf{x})}{||\textbf{x}||}$ is also approaching zero. It **will not** never reach $0$, but it gets infinitely close to it.

$(2)$ The limiting value of the fraction $\frac{f(\textbf{x})}{||\textbf{x}||}$ is zero when $||\textbf{x}||$ approaches zero.

Are my interpretations correct or not? To me it seems that they are not exactly the same. The reason I ask this, because I got confused with a notation in one of my math books. I wasn't quite sure which one of $(1)$ or $(2)$ they meant. If they mean the same thing then my problem is solved :)

In the above $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hi @GitGud $||\textbf{x}||\rightarrow 0$ simply means that the magnitude of the vector $\textbf{x}$ tends to zero as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Whether it will "actually reach $\mathbb 0$" is irrelevant to whether or not the limit exists.

Comment: @jjepsuomi You're just rewording the statement. Define it with symbols. **Edit:** Actually, nevermind, I misread something. I will delete my comment and make a new one.

Comment: They mean the same thing. And it isn't necessarily true that the second expression never reaches zero. If $f$ is zero in a neighborhood of $0$, it will "reach zero" while $\textbf{x}$ itself is some distance away from $0$.

Comment: $||\cdot||$ is a norm, e.g. the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: I'm sorry @GitGud I can't give you any more detailed definition, because I took this notation from my Calculus of Variations book and they did not define it in more detailed way than that. They defined only what $f, \textbf{x}$ and $||\cdot||$ mean. A function, argument and a norm.

Comment: I copy and pasted the wrong thing. What I want to ask is this. What is the definition of $\lim \limits_{\color{red}{||\textbf{x}||}\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(\textbf{x})}{||\textbf{x}||}=0$?

Comment: Hi @MPW okay, so they mean the same thing. Thank you for your help. What troubles me is the words "isn't necessarily true". "If $f$ is zero in a neighborhood of $0$", in that case I can understand what you said. The IFs trouble me x) sry for being so picky. To me its like saying that, its always true...but not always ;D

Comment: Hi @GitGud thank you for your help =) maybe this post will give you more information: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124846/understanding-part-of-a-theorem-of-calculus-of-variations. My question here refers to that question.

Comment: Convergence to zero doesn't necessarily mean asymptotic behavior. For example, both of the sequences $\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\frac15,\ldots$ and $\frac12,\frac13,0,0,0,0,\ldots$ converge to zero. In the first, no term of the sequence actually is zero, while in the second, the terms eventually do reach zero.

Comment: @MPW thank you, so what you're saying is that it depends on the case whether $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the same or not? It depends on the functions etc. we are dealing with?

Comment: However, you are controlling the input $x$, so it should approach zero without assuming the value of $0$. The output $f(x)/|x|$ is out of your control and may behave either way.

Comment: (1) and (2) are still the same

Comment: Okay, thank you very much @MPW could you post your comments as an answer? I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

What if $f(x)=x^2$ and $x\in (0,\infty)$. Would the following two be equivalent:

$$(1)\;\;\;|x|\rightarrow0,\;\;\; \frac{x^2}{x}=x\rightarrow0$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\lim_{|x|\rightarrow0} \frac{x^2}{x}=x=0$$